# How to Export Import Component On React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, inertiajs, laravel-10

I'm just learning laravel & react js.
I am trying to make a project in laravel and react js. So how can I export component TextInput (className) to my Login page.

TextInput.jsx :

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default forwardRef(
    function TextInput({ type = "text", className, isFocused = false, ...props }, ref) {
        const input = ref ? ref : useRef();

        useEffect(() => {
            if (isFocused) {
                input.current.focus();
            }
        }, []);

        return (
            <input
                {...props}
                type={type}
                className={
                    "rounded-2xl bg-form-bg py-[13px] px-7 w-full focus:outline-alerange focus:outline-none"
                }
                ref={input}
            />
        );
    }
);
```

Login.jsx script :

```
import React from "react";
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput";

export default function Login() {
    return (
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen min-h-screen bg-black text-white md:px-10 px-3">
            <div className="fixed top-[-50px] hidden lg:block">
                <img
                    src="/images/signup-image.png"
                    className="hidden laptopLg:block laptopLg:max-w-[450px] laptopXl:max-w-[640px]"
                    alt=""
                />
            </div>
            <div className="py-24 flex laptopLg:ml-[680px] laptopXl:ml-[870px]">
                <div>
                    <img src="/images/moonton-white.svg" alt="" />
                    <div className="my-[70px]">
                        <div className="font-semibold text-[26px] mb-3">
                            Welcome Back
                        </div>
                        <p className="text-base text-[#767676] leading-7">
                            Explore our new movies and get <br />
                            the better insight for your life
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <form className="w-[370px]">
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
                            <div>
                                <label className="text-base block mb-2">
                                    Email Address
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    placeholder="Email Address"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label className="text-base block mb-2">
                                    Password
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    name="password"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="grid space-y-[14px] mt-[30px]">
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="rounded-2xl bg-alerange py-[13px] text-center"
                            >
                                <span className="text-base font-semibold">
                                    Start Watching
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="sign_up.html"
                                className="rounded-2xl border border-white py-[13px] text-center"
                            >
                                <span className="text-base text-white">
                                    Create New Account
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to use className (email & password) from component/TextInput.jsx to pages/Login.jsx.

On this project I am using laravel 10

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are importing `forwardRef` from react so you just need to use the forwardRef wherever you need.
One more thing the `functions or hooks` which are imported from react cannot be exported by us as a component or so.

Try to export the text input instead of forwardRef
like,

```
export const TextInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
    );
});
```

And in `Login.jsx` you can import the `TextInput` by passing with its relevant path like,

```
import { TextInput } from "path/to/file";

<TextInput props={props} />
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) and some good tutorials for React.js [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=react%20js%20tutorial%20for%20beginners).

Comment: thanks, it was just wrong in <TextInput /> tag in login.jsx file :D

Answer (score 0):

To use the TextInput component in your Login page and replace the className of the email and password input fields, you can import the TextInput component and use it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput";
```

Replace the email and password input fields with the TextInput component, and pass the required props to it:

```
<div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
  <div>
    <label className="text-base block mb-2">
      Email Address
    </label>
    <TextInput
      type="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email Address"
      className="your-custom-classname"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label className="text-base block mb-2">
      Password
    </label>
    <TextInput
      type="password"
      name="password"
      placeholder="Password"
      className="your-custom-classname"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to add custom styles to the TextInput component, you can pass the className prop to it and add your custom styles like this:

```
<TextInput
  type="email"
  name="email"
  placeholder="Email Address"
  className="rounded-2xl bg-form-bg py-[13px] px-7 w-full focus:outline-alerange focus:outline-none your-custom-classname"
/>
```